# Installing vagrant-librarian-chef Has net-ssh Version Conflicts

Tags: ruby, vagrant, net-ssh

When trying to install vagrant-librarian-chef plugin for Vagrant 1.8.1 I get the following error

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.2.7
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.2.7
Installing the 'vagrant-librarian-chef' plugin. This can take a few minutes... 
The plugin(s) can't be installed due to the version conflicts below.
This means that the plugins depend on a library version that conflicts
with other plugins or Vagrant itself, creating an impossible situation
where Vagrant wouldn't be able to load the plugins.

You can fix the issue by either removing a conflicting plugin or
by contacting a plugin author to see if they can address the conflict.

Vagrant could not find compatible versions for gem "net-ssh":
  In Gemfile:
    vagrant (= 1.8.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      net-ssh (~> 3.0.1) x86-mingw32

    vagrant (= 1.8.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      net-scp (~> 1.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
        net-ssh (>= 2.6.5) x86-mingw32

    vagrant (= 1.8.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      net-scp (~> 1.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
        net-ssh (>= 2.6.5) x86-mingw32

    vagrant-librarian-chef (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      librarian-chef (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
        chef (>= 0.10) x86-mingw32 depends on
          net-ssh (~> 2.1.3) x86-mingw32
```

When I do `gem list net-ssh` I get the following back:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

net-ssh (3.0.2, 2.9.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.2.1)
```

Any help with what's wrong? I'm a total newbie to both ruby and vagrant which probably isn't helping the situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a conflict in the net-ssh version. Vagrant 1.8.1 uses `v3.0.1`, but vagrant-librarian-chef accepts versions up to `2.9`.

Downgrading the vagrant version to 1.7.4 solved the issue for me.